# How to rename all files in a directory to have an equal amount of digits?

Tags: perl

I took a lot of pictures with my camera and I wanted to make a timelapse out of them. The camera saved the pictures as picture1, picture2 ... picture956 etc but the timelapse software I'm using only accepts numbers of equal length like this: picture001, picture002, picture003 etc.

I thought Perl would be a good fit for this kind of problem so I gave it a shot. This is a shorter and translated version of the original code so if anything is unclear I can change it to the longer version.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

print "Give the path to the directory where the pictures are stored:\n";
my $filename = <STDIN>;

chomp $filename;
chdir $filename or die "Couldn't change the directory: $!\n";
my @files  = <*>;
#gives a list of all filehandles in the given directory

my $amount_of_digits = int( log($#files)/log(10) +1);
#how many digits should the new number have?
#Example: If there are 400 files -> 3 digits per file: 001, 002 etc

foreach my $file (@files){
    next if($file =~ /^\.$/);
    next if($file =~ /^\.\.$/);
    #skip the . and .. files
    print "$file\n";
    if ($file =~ /(\d+)/){
        my $amount_of_padded_zeroes = $amount_of_digits - length($1);
        if($amount_of_padded_zeroes > 0){
            my $new_number =  '0' x $amount_of_padded_zeroes . $1;     
            (my $new_name = $file) =~ s/$1/$new_number/;
            print "Changing name too: $new_name\n"; 
            rename ($file, $new_name) or die "Couldn't rename the file: $!";
        }
    }
}

print "Program completed. Press any key to continue.\n";
my $einde = <STDIN>;
```

The code works but I wanted to know if there is a better/cleaner/shorter/more Pearlesque way to do this. I'm learning Perl for uni so any feedback is welcome. I suspect this problem is so trivial in Perl that there might be readable one-liners that are able to replace all of this.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Please repost to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd also encourage you to post for review, as there is a lot of chance for improvement in your good effort.  Still, here is a rough road map for one approach:  (1) extract numbers from names (using regex), and keep the parts `@parts = map { /(.*?)([0-9]+)$/; [ $1, $2 ] } @names;`  (2) Find longest number, `$ml = List::Util::max map { length $_->[1] } @parts` (3) Format numbers to desired length and put it back `@new_names = map { $->[0] . sprintf "%0${ml}d", $->[1] } @parts;` (4) rename files.  /// This is written quickly with little thought and only a basic check

Comment: A couple of notes on the above.  (1) one can also do `map { [ /(.*?)([0-9]+)$/ ] }`  since regex returns a list (of two) captures and so we get our arrayref  (2) By "_Find longest number_" I meant "Find the maximal length among those numbers" (as strings)  -- that doesn't identify what that number is (not needed)  (3) "_put it back_" meant "put the strings back together"

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think I'd change very much. Here's my version.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

print "Give the path to the directory where the pictures are stored:\n";
chomp(my $dir = <STDIN>);

chdir $dir or die "Couldn't change the directory: $!\n";
my @files  = <*>;
#gives a list of all filehandles in the given directory

my $amount_of_digits = int( log($#files)/log(10) +1);
#how many digits should the new number have?
#Example: If there are 400 files -> 3 digits per file: 001, 002 etc

foreach (@files) {
    next if -d;
    #skip the . and .. files

    print "$_\n";
    if (/(\d+)/) {
        my $new_number = sprintf "%0${amount_of_digits}d", $1;
        (my $new_name = $_) =~ s/$1/$new_number/;
        print "Changing name to: $new_name\n"; 
        rename ($_, $new_name) or die "Couldn't rename the file: $!";
    }
}

print "Program completed. Press any key to continue.\n";
my $einde = <STDIN>;
```

1. I've combined the `chomp()` into the line that reads from `STDIN`.
2. I renamed the variable that holds the directory name. It's now called `$dir`.
3. I use `$_` as the loop variable - because many of the operations inside the loop use `$_` by default, so it simplifies some of the code.
4. Instead of looking for `.` and `..` specifically, I just look for directories (with `-d`).
5. I use `sprintf()` as a simpler(?) way to generate a zero-padded version of the number.

Hope this is useful.